# Getting the location of two different modules

Tags: omnet++

I have 2 types of submodules in my network.

1. `AdhocHost` which is standard definition in INET framework.
2. module of type `IMobility` with its mobility type
   of type `RandomWPMobility`, both are standard INET modules.

I can get the location of modules of type `AdhocHost` by this code:

```
module = simulation.getModuleByPath("Mynet.host[1]");
c = MobilityAccess().get(module)->getCurrentPosition();
```

`host[*]` being of type `AdhocHost`.

But when I replace `host[1]` with blockage[1] (blockage is of type `IMobility`), before running simulation this error appears:

> Error in module (MyMobileController) Mynet.mymobilecontroller during
>   network initialization: Model error: module (IMobility)mobility not
>   found.

The module `mymobilecontroller` is the module that contains this fraction of code. This module does not need to move. Its duty is just to record the location of mobile modules in the network.

What is the problem?

Comment: please accept the answer that solved you problem, for future users. Also edit your question to add the code modifications you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The 'MobilityAccess' code expects that you pass a *NetworkNode* to it that contains a submodule named `mobility` with the type `IMobility`. In the first case it is true (with a StandardHost) however in the second case you pass directly an module that has a type of IMobility.

Long story short, a module with a type of IMobility is meant to exist *INSIDE* of a network node and not at the network level.

Solution: I'm not sure what is the blockage module supposed to do, but it should NOT be a type of IMobility, instead it should be a module that *contains* a submodule with a type IMobility.

Comment: Thanks for your help, man! I did as you said and that fixed the problem.

Comment: @Masoud please accept the answer that solved your problem, for future reference